# how to create multi threads with multi request and response?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

```
Public Function getheaders(ByVal add As String) As String
    Dim req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://" & add)
    req.Timeout = 2000
    Try
        Using response As WebResponse = req.GetResponse()
            Dim aa As String = response.Headers("WWW-Authenticate")
            Return aa
          End Using
    Catch ex As WebException
        Using response As WebResponse = ex.Response
            If ex.Status.ToString = "Timeout" Then
                Return "none"
                Else
                Try
                    Dim aa As String = response.Headers("WWW-Authenticate")
                    Catch exa As Exception
                    Return "none"
                    End Try
            End If
        End Using
    End Try
End Function


//////////////////// CREATIN THREADS ///////////////////////

 For i = 0 To 255
        Dim t As Thread = New System.Threading.Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf getheaders))
        t.IsBackground = True
        t.Start("192.168.1." & ai.ToString)
    Next
```

this works fine but whene all threads are finished i cant use internet any more till after waiting 5 minutes or repair my connexion

WHERE IS THE ERROR OR IS THERE AN OTHER WAY TO MAKE THIS ??

Comment: What error do you get if you try to use the internet after running that code? How do you repair your connection? Are all of the requests to the same web server? Is it possible that your proxy is throttling the number of requests you make?

Comment: @JimMischel thanks for the comment , the error is that i loss the connexion internet on the computer im connected by wireless so i disocnnect and reconnect , no the requests are not to the same server and no im sure that i dont use any proxy and my country does not use a proxy , I RECEIVE ALL THE RESPONSE OF THE 255 PARALLEL REQUEST SO GOOD BUT I CAN NOT DO ANYMORE AFTER THAT BECAUSE CONNEXION IS DOWN